# My tensorflow model doesn't support multi-classification, Why is that?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to do the mnist classification. Here is the dataset

```
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

mnist = datasets.load_digits()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    mnist.data.reshape((-1,8,8,1)), mnist.target.reshape(-1, 1), test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

Here is the code to build the tensorflow model, **note** that the last line uses `units=1`

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=6, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=120, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation = 'softmax'))
```

Here is the code to compile and train the model.

```
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, 
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), 
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1)
```

the code is runnable though, the accuracy is bad, because I have to set `units=1` for the last layer of my model.

When I set it to `units=10`, I got this error

> ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 10) are incompatible

**Note** Because of the error, I have to set the number of output neurons to `10`. However, I don't want my model output a single neuron, I want it output 10 neurons as mnist is 10-classes, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems:

- Set the last layer units correctly
- Choose the appropriate loss function

**In a multi-classification task (with number of class > 2) you have to set the last layer units equal to the number of classes** (`units=10` in you case).

For the correct choice of the loss you have two possibilities:

**1. possibility**: if you have 1D integer encoded target, you can use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` as loss function

```
n_class = 3
n_features = 100
n_sample = 1000

X = np.random.randint(0,10, (n_sample,n_features))
y = np.random.randint(0,n_class, n_sample)

inp = Input((n_features,))
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(inp)
out = Dense(n_class, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(inp, out)
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X, y, epochs=3)
```

**2. possibility**: if you have one-hot encoded your target in order to have 2D shape `(n_samples, n_class)`, you can use `categorical_crossentropy`

```
n_class = 3
n_features = 100
n_sample = 1000

X = np.random.randint(0,10, (n_sample,n_features))
y = pd.get_dummies(np.random.randint(0,n_class, n_sample)).values

inp = Input((n_features,))
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(inp)
out = Dense(n_class, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(inp, out)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X, y, epochs=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your models outputs a single neuron, and you apply softmax. The latter normalizes the values of the last layer into a "probability distribution", i.e., all values are between 0 and 1 and add up to 1.

If you only have a single neuron whose value should "add up to 1", the output must necessarily always be 1. In other words, you cannot really learn anything with such a model.

Instead, design the last layer so that the number of output neurons is equal to the number of classes.

Why you're seeing the `ValueError` is hard to say because you're not showing where it's happening in your code.

Comment: Thank you. I don't want my model output a single neuron, I want it output 10 neurons as mnist is 10-classes, how do I do that?

Comment: `units=10`, like you have already tried, and change your loss function to `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`. Just follow the TensorFlow tutorials to get a hang of it.